Add custom payload to actioncable broadcast method
Im using actioncable to broadcast data by websocket but i need this specific format
{
  "type": "any_type",
  "identifier": "{\"channel\":\"RoomChannel\",\"channel_id\":\"a1453cac-740b-4871-b0a1-208659b0dbe6\"}",
  "message": {
    "id": "9db64c6a-01dc-4777-ac2f-d55051115a29",
    "message": "some data",
    "userID": "4eed198c-d9b4-4789-99ca-fcc0635b2082",
    "chatChannelID": "a1453cac-740b-4871-b0a1-208659b0dbe6",
    "date": "2024-04-17T13:35:39.848Z"
  }
}


and im not being able to do this, i only was able to get
{
  "identifier": "{\"channel\":\"RoomChannel\",\"channel_id\":\"a1453cac-740b-4871-b0a1-208659b0dbe6\"}",
  "message": {
    "id": "9db64c6a-01dc-4777-ac2f-d55051115a29",
    "message": "some data",
    "userID": "4eed198c-d9b4-4789-99ca-fcc0635b2082",
    "chatChannelID": "a1453cac-740b-4871-b0a1-208659b0dbe6",
    "date": "2024-04-17T13:35:39.848Z",
     "type": "any_type"
  }
}

i made a patch to modify the broadcast method from actioncable rails files but i was not able to achieve this.
The idea would be to use something like this
ActionCable.server.broadcast(room_channel(chat_message.chat_channel), chat_message.json_data, 'here_the_type')


Why don't merge this type to chat_message.json_data instead of dubious monkeypatch?
